# Why does this function accept the 2nd param

Tags: ocaml

The function `aux` only has one param `n`. Why can it accept `list` at the bottom?

```ml
# let length list =
    let rec aux n = function
      | [] -> n
      | _ :: t -> aux (n + 1) t
    in
    aux 0 list;;

    val length : 'a list -> int = <fun>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function` keyword will match the last argument, even it’s not declared in the left side of `=`.

Compare with `match .. with`, the `match` needs the argument name show up.

Answer (score 2):

The `function` keyword introduces a function which takes a single argument, which it pattern matches.

This is equivalent to:

```
let length lst =
  let rec aux n lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> n
    | _ :: t -> aux (n + 1) t
  in
  aux 0 lst
```

*Or...*

```
let length lst =
  let rec aux n = 
    fun lst ->
      match lst with
      | [] -> n
      | _ :: t -> aux (n + 1) t
  in
  aux 0 lst
```

Answer (score 2):

The `function` expression produces a function of one argument.

```
# function [] -> 0 | _ -> 1;;
- : 'a list -> int = <fun>
```

Now, if you write a function `f` that takes a parameter `n`, and whose body contains `function`, as follows:

```
# let f n = function [] -> 0 | _ -> n;;
val f : int -> 'a list -> int = <fun>
```

Then `f` is a function that takes `n` and returns a function of a single argument.

```
# f 3;;
- : '_weak1 list -> int = <fun>
```

The returned value is a function that takes a list of some unknown type of values, and returns an integer (the `_weak` prefix is related to [Weak Type Variables](https://ocamlverse.github.io/content/weak_type_variables.html), this is not important here).

Since the returned value is a function, you can apply it:

```
# (f 3) ["test"];;
- : int = 3
```

You can drop the parentheses around `f 3` because that's how function application is grouped by default:

```
# f 3 ["test"];;
- : int = 3
```

So what looks like a function taking two arguments is in fact a function taking one argument, evaluating to a function to which we apply the second argument.

(See also [Currying](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2014sp/lectures/3/lec03.html))

Comment: it's a good explaining of currying, but seems at the bottom of function body, the function `aux` is called already before `length` return it.

Comment: @Jam Yes, in your example there is another layer around aux, but the explanation here is only about the interaction between `aux` and the anonymous `fun`; the expression `aux 0 lst` calls `aux 0`, which gives a function, then applies it to `lst`

Comment: Every function only ever takes one argument and only one argument is ever applied to a function. Everything else is syntactic sugar (or the optimizer doing it's work).  So `let f a b = ...` is `let f = fun a b -> ...` is `let f = function a -> function b -> ...` and `f 1 2` is `let f' = f 1 in f' 2`. You can even do this to infix operators: `let inc = (+) 1`